# Racket mutable hash to immutable hash

Tags: hashmap, hashtable, racket, immutability

I am using the procedure `hash-set` to set a value in a `hash?`. It seems to require the hash to be `immutable?`. So far I could not find a better way to transform a mutable hash into an immutable hash than the following:

(make-immutable-hash (hash->list myhash))

The hash is some `yaml`, which I am reading from a file and the `yaml` module gives me a mutable hash. For example I have the following code:

```
(hash-set yaml-hash
                "content"
                (make-immutable-hash
                 (hash->list
                  (my-hash-map content-hash
                               (lambda (key value)
                                 (cons key
                                       (markdown-to-html value)))))))
```

Is there a better way to transform a mutable hash into an immutable one, for the purpose of updating it? Or should I go a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hash is mutable to begin with, you can modify it directly using `hash-set!`:

```
(hash-set! yaml-hash <key> <new-value>)
```

The above will change the value of the hash in-place, whereas `hash-set` will return a *new* hash, which you'll have to store or reassign somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

> I could not find a better way to transform a mutable hash into an immutable hash than the following:
>
> ```lisp
> (make-immutable-hash (hash->list myhash))
> ```

You can use a [`for/hash` comprehension](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fhash%29%29) and [`in-hash` sequence](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-hash%29%29) to iterate through the entries of the mutable hash one at a time instead of first building a list of them all:

```lisp
;;; Contract: (-> hash? (and/c hash? immutable?))
(define (hash->immutable-hash table)
  (if (immutable? table) 
      table ;; If hash is already immutable, just return it
      (for/hash ([(k v) (in-mutable-hash my-table)]) (values k v))))
```

Comment: Had this problem recently, and didn't like the `hash->list` approach any better than OP did. Settled on this alternative.